# Compatibility of the new sdk

Tags: android

When developing with features introduced with in the new Android OS version, does one have to write an entirely different application structure to deal with older devices, or is there some sort of support mechanism for these situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honeycomb does not support the older devices. The new Android OS version is only targetting tablets and similar devices. If you want to create applications for smaller, more common handheld devices you should use Gingerbread. This means new features introduced in Honeycomb are at this time not available for phones and similar devices.

So yes, you will need to develop seperate applications for tablets and older devices.